# extract two rows at a time and put it in a list

Tags: r

I need to extract two rows at a time and put it in a list. Basically I have an output from a program which gives me some 50 2x2 matrices as data (number of lines in data 100) and I need to extract each matrix for computation to be done later. Here is some simulated data and what I tried. I am doing something wrong. It just gives me the last row.

```
dat <- matrix(1:12, 6, 2, byrow = TRUE)
dat
       #[,1] [,2]
 # [1,]    1    2
 # [2,]    3    4
 # [3,]    5    6
 # [4,]    7    8
 # [5,]    9   10
#  [6,]   11   12


# This is what I want my list to look like

  list(dat[1:2,],dat[3:4,],dat[5:6,])

 #   [[1]]
  #       [,1] [,2]
  #  [1,]    1    2
   # [2,]    3    4

#  [[2]]
#       [,1] [,2]
 # [1,]    5    6
 # [2,]    7    8

#  [[3]]
 #      [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    9   10
 # [2,]   11   12


  # I tried the following
list<-list()
 l<-NULL
 for (i in 1:nrow(dat)-1)
 {
   l<-dat[i:i+1,]

   list<-list(rbind(l,l))
 }
 list
 # [[1]]
  #  [,1] [,2]
 # l   11   12
 # l   11   12
```

Comment: Try `split(as.data.frame(dat), as.integer(gl(nrow(dat), 2, nrow(dat))))` or `lapply(split(dat, as.integer(gl(nrow(dat), 2, nrow(dat)))), matrix, ncol=2)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. All of the three answers work. But instead of $1, $2 and $3 how do it get [[1]], [[2]] and [[3]]. Basically the output that I have listed above.

Comment: Delete the names with `names(list) <- NULL`

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Just figured that out by myself too ! I am also able to extract each matrix now

Comment: @user24318, `setNames(split(as.data.frame(dat), ceiling(1:nrow(dat)/2)), nm = NULL)`